# Trying to create a date range to fetch data from API

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

So I'm trying to create a date range to fetch data from an API. So I have a start date and an end date which I want pass in the command line and I want to get data for those dates only.

Aim is to get 3 full days of date, 8th, 9th and 10th December.

```
input_start = '20211208' #passed in at command line
input_end = '20211210' #passed in at command line

start_datetime = datetime.strptime(input_start, '%Y%m%d') #this prints  2021-12-08 00:00:00 which is what i want

end_datetime = datetime.strptime(input_end, '%Y%m%d') #this prints 2021-12-10 00:00:00 which means it's not covering the entire day of 10th Dec
```

How can I modify my code to make sure `end_datetime` covers the entire day of 10th Dec?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add a day:

```
end_datetime += timedelta(days=1)
```

BTW: you might need to adapt the import, like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```